# PHP how echo Js Custom alert

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, echo

hello I picked up a custom alert from the internet and would like to implement in my php echo alert, already tried several ways but I can not find the correct syntax. help please

I think I need to pass the "echo" to the javascript and call the function when you call the "echo" in PHP, but I'm not having any luck

```
  <script>
  function CustomAlert(){
this.render = function(){
    var winW =  window.innerWidth;
    var winH = window.innerHeight;
    var dialogoverlay = document.getElementById('dialogoverlay');
    var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialogbox');
    dialogoverlay.style.display = "block";
    dialogoverlay.style.height = winH+"px";
    dialogbox.style.left = "20px";
    dialogbox.style.top = "70px";
    dialogbox.style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('dialogboxhead').innerHTML = "Login Processado com Sucesso";
    document.getElementById('dialogboxbody').innerHTML = "Seja Bem Vindo";
    document.getElementById('dialogboxfoot').innerHTML = '<button onclick="Alert.ok()">OK</button>';


}
this.ok = function(){
    document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";

}
}
var Alert = new CustomAlert();

</script>
```

and php:

```
   <?php
  $email=$_POST['email'];
  $senha=$_POST['senha'];
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT email, senha FROM clientes WHERE email = '$email' and senha = '$senha'") or die(mysql_error());
  $row = mysql_num_rows($sql);
  if($row > 0 ) {
session_start();
$_SESSION['email']=$_POST['email'];
$_SESSION['senha']=$_POST['senha'];
echo '<script>';
echo 'Alert.render("Login efetuado com sucesso")';
echo '</script>';
echo "<script>loginsucessfully()</script>";


    } else {
echo "Usuario ou senha invalidos";
echo "<script>loginfailed()</script>";
    }

   ?>
```

Comment: I need call the var Alert.render on my PHP echo

Answer (score 2):

To pass a variable from PHP to Javascript:

```
var something = <?php echo $something; ?>;
```

As a side note, the semicolon in the PHP tags isn't necessary since it's only one line of code; it's just a matter of style.

Comment: ok thanks, but how to Javascript to PHP, i just need when my user login sucessfully show this custom alert.. can you show me how ? please

Comment: ok but i've declared var Alert = CustomAlert(); how i can pass this var Alert to echo on php, like var Alert = (CustomAlert()  + <?php echo $something; ?>; i cant figure it out

Comment: Are you just trying to display a simple JS alert? If so, you can use `alert(<?php echo $something; ?>);`.

Comment: trying to use my custom alert js on php echo alert .. what i dont understand is how echo an JS var, but the var calls a function so i cant use var something = <?php echo $something; ?>;

Comment: I need call the var Alert.render on my PHP echo

Comment: @Frank021 I'm having trouble understanding what exactly you're trying to accomplish. Could you explain a bit further?

Comment: of course, I picked up a code that makes a custom alert, from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-RLE2Q7OzME and in my code I have several confirmations of insert and delete data in the database .. I am using android webview and not like usual alert php (echo alert () ) that appeared on the screen, instead I would like to put this js alert with css on my echos

Comment: The code is good, you can simply call the function using onload="Alert.render();" our onclick="Alert.render();"  but i dont want that .. need this information as a warning called by echo when data is inserted or deleted from database

Answer (score 1):

To do this you can either program a javascript function that submits a form - or you can use ajax / jquery. [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Or maybe this can help you .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var foo = '<?php echo $foo ?>';
</script>
```